# Identify MS Excel or MS Access attachments and warn to check contents

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment, mailitem

Personal identifying information (PII) is often inadvertently transmitted through non-encrypted emails.  Most of the times these data are stored in Excel or Access spreadsheets.

I'd like to identify Access or Excel attachments after hitting send and ask "There are Access or Excel files attached to this email, are you sure these do not contain PII?"

The criteria for identifying "xlsx" or "accdb" in the attachment name I just don't get.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If Right([attachment_Name],4) = xlsx then

    answer = MsgBox("There are Access or Excel files attached to this email, are you sure these do not contain PHI?",vbYesNo)

    If answer = vbNo 
        Cancel = True
    Else

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is interesting that Access databases are sent over email. While Access is a file server database compared to its client server counterparts (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.), it still is a multiple user application intended to run on a network and should not be treated as a flat file document like a spreadsheet. Plus, mdb/accdb files can expand larger than email attachment limits which may require zip files.

Comment: Access shouldn't send as an email.  When trying it _should_ say something along the lines of:  "This item contains attachments that are potentially unsafe..yada.yada.yada. Do you want to send anyway?"  When I send it the email arrives with the attachment stripped out and a message saying "Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachments:".  This is just Outlook though, so could be different with other email apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim bolSensitiveAttach As Boolean
Dim answer As Double

Set Msg = Item

bolSensitiveAttach = False
If Msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To Msg.Attachments.Count
         If Right(Msg.Attachments(i).FileName, 3) = "xls" Or  _
                Left(Right(Msg.Attachments(i).FileName, 4), 3) = "xls" Or _
                Right(Msg.Attachments(i).FileName, 5) = "accdb" Or _
                Right(Msg.Attachments(i).FileName, 3) = "mdb" Then  
                     bolSensitiveAttach = True
         End If

    Next i
End If

If bolSensitiveAttach = True Then
    answer = MsgBox("There are Access or Excel files attached to this" _
                 & "mail, are you sure these do not contain PHI?", vbYesNo)
    If answer = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

EDITED TO INCLUDE .mdb extension and xls* extensions (xlsm, xlsx...) instead of just xlsx.  Thanks for the suggestion Parfait.

Comment: Consider adding the older Access mdb file version since you do the older Excel xls version.

Comment: You can ignore the `=TRUE` in the `IF` statement.  `bolSensitiveAttach` is TRUE/FALSE itself so you're saying `IF TRUE = TRUE THEN`.  I prefer to name my variables something like `ContainsSensitiveAttach`.  You can then write `IF ContainsSensitiveAttach THEN` which almost sounds like English.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FileSystemObject` to grab the extension:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim olAtt As Attachment
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim sExt As String
    Dim bSafe As Boolean

    If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        bSafe = True
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For Each olAtt In Item.Attachments
            sExt = oFSO.GetExtensionName(olAtt.FileName)
            If sExt Like "xls*" Or sExt Like "accd*" Or sExt = "mdb" Then
                bSafe = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next olAtt

        If Not bSafe Then
            If MsgBox("This email contains an Access or Excel file." & vbCr & _
                      "Do you wish to continue?", vbCritical + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

        Set oFSO = Nothing

    End If
End Sub
```

I've included for Access, but pretty sure that doesn't send by default.