# Way to warn user when attaching a non-pdf file to an email in MS Outlook 2010?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, attachment

I have an employee who attaches word documents, excel documents and other editable documents into emails and "forgets" to save them as a pdf before emailing them. I would like to have a way to warn the user rather than prevent the action as there is times we still need to email the documents.

Is this possible. We have a MS Outlook 2010 Professional.

Can I capture the add attachment event on the default form in VBA and get the file extension and if not a pdf, display a simple message box. Can I do this on the default email form?

Comment: Try this test If Right(Msg.Attachments(i).FileName, 3) <> "pdf" Then bolSensitiveAttach = True in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509063/ms-outlook-vba-identify-ms-excel-or-ms-access-attachments-in-email-and-warn-to

Comment: I could not find that answer searching on here. That post you linked was exactly the example I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code I ended up using as these were the 3 main file types that kept getting sent not as PDF files.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim STRfn As String, STRft As String, FileFlag As Boolean, Mbox
FileFlag = False
Mbox = ""

For Each oAtt In Item.Attachments
    STRfn = oAtt.FileName
    STRft = Right(STRfn, Len(STRfn) - InStrRev(STRfn, "."))

    Select Case STRft

        Case "xls", "xlsx", "xlsm"
            Mbox = MsgBox("The attachment: " & STRfn & " is an EXCEL document and should be a PDF before sending this email." & vbCrLf & "DO YOU WANT TO SEND ANYWAY?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "NON PDF ATTACHMENT")
            If Mbox = 7 Then
                FileFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Case "dox", "docx"
            Mbox = MsgBox("The attachment: " & STRfn & " is an WORD document and should be a PDF before sending this email." & vbCrLf & "DO YOU WANT TO SEND ANYWAY?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "NON PDF ATTACHMENT")
            If Mbox = 7 Then
                FileFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Case "vsd", "vss", "vst"
            Mbox = MsgBox("The attachment: " & STRfn & " is an VISIO DRAWING and should be a PDF before sending this email." & vbCrLf & "DO YOU WANT TO SEND ANYWAY?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "NON PDF ATTACHMENT")
            If Mbox = 7 Then
                FileFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If

    End Select

Next

If FileFlag = True Then Cancel = True
```

End Sub